# Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly. Ionic React Sign In and Sign Up Form AWS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

New to AWS, I'm trying to connect my registration and login form to AWS.

What I expected:

- Create a user in my userpool with signUp
- Log in to my apps with signIn

What is happening:

> Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly

What I did:

- Create my UserPool on AWS
- Create an IAM user on AWS
- `Amplify Configure`
- `Amplify Init`
- `Amplify import auth`
- `Amplify push`
- Add signUp component

```
async function signUp() {
    try {
      const { user } = await Auth.signUp({
        username: email,
        password,
        attributes: {
          'custom:code_postal': codePostal, // custom attribute, not standard
          'custom:ville': ville,
          'custom:pays': Pays,
          address: adresse,
          family_name: nom,
          given_name: prenom,
          'custom:marque': Marque,
          'custom:modele': modele,
          'custom:version': Version,
          'custom:puissance_batterie': PuissanceBat,
        },
        autoSignIn: { // optional - enables auto sign in after user is confirmed
          enabled: true,
        }
      });
      console.log(user);
      history.push("../tab/tab1");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error signing up:', error);
    }
  }
```

- Add a signIn component

```
async function signIn() {
    try {
      const user = await Auth.signIn(email, password);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error signing in', error);
    }
  }
```

Add the aws-exports.d.ts file (aws-exports.js was not found in my code)

```
declare const awsmobile: Record<string, any> export default awsmobile;
```

```
Ionic cap sync android
```

```
Ionic cap open
```

- I launch the app and the following error message appears:

```
 File: https://localhost/assets/index-75803d82.js - Line 222 - Msg: [ERROR] 47:44.22 AuthError - Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly. The configuration object is missing required auth properties. This error is typically caused by one of the following scenarios:
 
 1. Did you run amplify pushafter adding auth viaamplify add auth`? See https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#amplify-project-setup
 
 for more information 2. This could also be caused by multiple conflicting versions of amplify packages, see (https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/troubleshooting/upgrading/q/platform/js)
 
 for help upgrading Amplify packages.
```

What I tried:

- Create another UserPool with amplify add auth with the default config

I managed to register someone
It worked once, but then I got the same error

I tried also this code, which make login work but not with my own code, I didn't try register:

```
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify'; import awsConfig from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(awsConfig);

setupIonicReact();

const App: React.FC = () => ( <IonApp> <IonReactRouter> <Menu /> <IonTabs> <IonRouterOutlet id='main'> <Route exact path="/"> <Redirect to="/pages/Welcome/Welcome" /> </Route> <Route path="/tab1" component={Tab1} /> <Route path="/tab2" component={Tab2} /> <Route path="/tab3" component={Tab3} /> </IonRouterOutlet> <IonTabBar className='ion-tab-bar' slot="bottom"> <IonTabButton tab="Tab1" href="/Tab1"> <IonIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={home} /> <IonLabel>Home</IonLabel> </IonTabButton> <IonTabButton tab="Tab2" href="/Tab2"> <IonIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={speedometer} /> <IonLabel>Compteurs</IonLabel> </IonTabButton> <IonTabButton tab="Tab3" href="/Tab3"> <IonIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={navigateOutline} /> <IonLabel>Trouver ma borne</IonLabel> </IonTabButton> </IonTabBar> </IonTabs>

  {/* Routes pour les autres pages */}
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/pages/Contact/Contact" component={Contact} />
    <Route path="/pages/FAQ/FAQ" component={FAQ} />
    <Route path="/pages/AboutUs/AboutUs" component={AboutUs} />
    <Route path="/pages/AccountPage/AccountPage" component={AccountPage} />
    <Route path="/pages/Welcome/welcome" component={WelcomePage} />
  </Switch>
</IonReactRouter>
);

export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

If I haven't been clear on some points, please let me know. Thank you in advance for your clarification.